# 2002 Toyota Highlander V6 ticking noise and rough accelerating

Tags: engine

**Vehicle:** 2002 Toyota Highlander V6 (2WD)

**Symptoms:**

- When I'm driving around when I drive above 55 mph and am approaching 60 mph I get some pretty bad rumbling in the entire car.
- Ticking/Rattling noise (imagine if you threw something hard in a blender and turned it on)
- The gas consumption increased
- Strong scent of gasoline whenever I get out of the car
- Misfire codes for cylinder 2,4,6
- Engine bank 2 running too lean

**Recent things I have done (after ticking started)**

- Replaced Spark plugs
- Cleaned MAF sensor
- Changed the PCV valve

I'm kind of lost on what this could be. Someone suggested bad fuel injectors but I'm not really sure about that one. I was doing some reading and I thought I should maybe change the O2 sensor just for good measure.

Comment: Gather data first, don't replace anything else. You may get lucky with a new AFR sensor, maybe not.  What are the fuel trims? What is the AFR sensor doing? Where is the rattling coming from? Is it from the engine? Under a valve cover?

Comment: Ok, so I ended up changing the AFR sensor and I think that got rid of the rough acceleration, but I'm still having knocking noises. To me it sound like it's coming below the valve cover, I was thinking it might be something to do with the timing chain or belt.

Comment: Your so close!! Lefter bearings a wide man once suggested!!!YOU OH ME BIG !!!